# What SSD support changes are there in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, customization, ssd

For Ubuntu 10.10 I put together a list of optimizations and configuration options that needed tweaking for optimum SSD support:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MagicFab/SSDchecklist

I am wondering what has changed and what is now default/unneeded in terms of SSD support in Ubuntu 11.04?

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing has changed sine 10.10, but in 10.10 and I think 10.04 as well, you don't need to worry about partition alignment since the default alignment is 1 mb.

Comment: What brand(s) of SSD do you use and what are your references for your answer ?

Comment: I have an OCZ and am a contributing developer that has done a good bit of work in the disk management area.